# RangeError: Invalid time value with formatDistanceToNow() date-fns

Tags: node.js, date-fns

I have a response object from `mongoose` in server like

```
{
    "_id": "6197539dba5dbbefab5ed408",
    "username": "Alice",
    "category": "csharp",
    "title": "convert number to string in C#",
    "status": "public",
    "createdAt": "2021-11-19T07:34:53.506Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-11-25T07:44:28.385Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

In Client-side, I want to parse and display the `createdAt` property as the distance time to now
using `formatDistanceToNow()` from `date-fns` npm package.

```
formatDistanceToNow(createdAt)
```

But got the `RangeError: Invalid time value`.

Comment: Very easy in moment js. https://jsfiddle.net/cwo07hsu/

Comment: @Erenn, I know there are other packages, `moment`  is included. However, it seems too heavy!